# CMake and libssl installed correctly but gets error whenever I try to run cmake anywhere

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-22.04, libssl

Hi there I've been stuck on this error for quite a while. I am installing cmake on a Ubuntu22.04 machine and keep getting this error
`cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried removing and reinstalling cmake. I also tried installing libssl like `sudo apt install libssl-dev`. All the installings didn't give me any error, however whenever I even type cmake it would give me this error. I have also tried soft linking libssl like I have seen some other posts suggested but it would just give me new errors as the following:

`cmake: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version 'libssl.so.10' not found (required by cmake)`

Any thoughts or help on this?